# How to apply Custom Angular JS on slick-dots > li

Tags: angularjs, slick.js

I'll try to apply custom JS code on slick-dot, but it not apply,

```
$('.slick-dots > li').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('custom');
 });
```

How to Implement this,

Comment: What does that have to do with angularjs. All I see is jQuery code.

Comment: It is a javascript question, but I'm assuming your `ul` tag has the class `slick-dots` assigned to it?

Comment: I want to implement code for Angular js, please give me a Example that is apply for Angular JS

Comment: An example of what? The documentation is full of examples. Have you read it? First hint: forget that jQuery exists. Don't even include it when you start to practice with angular.